# long press and touchesBegan

Tags: ios, uiview, touchesbegan, touchesmoved

When I detect long press in my `ViewController` I show popup menu (add `UIView` as a subview). When long press ends I hide my menu (remove `UIView` from superview). So my menu is visible only when user touches the screen. Problem is that when I am holding and moving finger without touching up, my menu doesn't call `touchesBegan` or `touchesMoved` so I can't choose any button from menu. Is there another way than passing event from `ViewController`? I would like to do this in my `UIView`. Help, please.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to add `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to your ViewControllers's view.
Like that:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
```

In the implementation `handlePanGesture` your should find recognizer's translation relatively to your popup view.

```
-(void)handlePanGesture:(id)sender {
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer = sender;
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.contentView];
        //Here you can use translation to detect what button touched with gesture
    }
}
```